# JWT how to logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt

- Ruby 2.2.4
- Rails 4.1.8
- Devise 3.4.1

Hello People,
I follwed a tutorial (https://github.com/jimjeffers/rails-devise-cors-jwt-example), which overrides Devise to pass a JWT when authenticating remotely via JSON. However I want to improve this app with a logout function. But how do I do that? Actually with this code from the tutorial, once I am successfully authenticated, I cannot sign out or sign up again:

```
 You are already signed in.

    Welcome#index

    Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
```

The question is, how can I do that? How can I implement, that the user can log out or sign up again?

Here is a part of the code: 
**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # Disable CSRF protection
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  # Be sure to enable JSON.
  respond_to :html, :json
end
```

**session_controller.rb**

```
# This is an example of how to extend the devise sessions controller
# to support JSON based authentication and issuing a JWT.
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # Require our abstraction for encoding/deconding JWT.
  require 'auth_token'


  # Disable CSRF protection
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  # Be sure to enable JSON.
  respond_to :html, :json

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create

    # This is the default behavior from devise - view the sessions controller source:
    # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L16
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?

    # Here we're deviating from the standard behavior by issuing our JWT
    # to any JS based client.
    token = AuthToken.issue_token({ user_id: resource.id })
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {user: resource.email, token: token} }
    end

    # The default behavior would have been to simply fire respond_with:
    # respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```

**api_controller.rb**

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  # No action on this controller is accessible without a
  # supplying a valid token.
  before_filter :verify_jwt_token

  def test
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {'sample' => 'data'}}
    end
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # We depend on our auth_token module here.
  require 'auth_token'
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  # protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  protected
    ##
    # This method can be used as a before filter to protect
    # any actions by ensuring the request is transmitting a
    # valid JWT.
    def verify_jwt_token
      head :unauthorized if request.headers['Authorization'].nil? ||
          !AuthToken.valid?(request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last)
    end
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
  get '/api/test', to: 'api#test'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

**lib/auth_token.rb**

```
require 'jwt'

module AuthToken
  def AuthToken.issue_token(payload)
    payload['exp'] = 24.hours.from_now.to_i # Set expiration to 24 hours.
    JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
  end

  def AuthToken.valid?(token)
    begin
      JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
    rescue
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea or suggestions would really help me. I struggle with this problem for many days

UPDATE: here is my Interface from Android app, how could I implement the delete function?

```
public interface Interface {

    //This method is used for "POST"
    @FormUrlEncoded

    @POST("/")
    void postData(@Field("method") String method,
                  @Field("email") String username,
                  @Field("password") String password,
                  Callback<ServerResponse> serverResponseCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Florent said, on the client you just have to delete the token (remove it from your SharedPreferences or any other persistent storage you are using to store the current token) and for the server side you have a few options as follows from best to okay.

Refresh tokens: The best option and you can read about it [here](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/). Essentially you have two kind of tokens an access and a refresh token. The refresh token is used to renew the access token once it expires. For instance, in your current approach of 24 hours, the users will need to login every day. But if you logout, you remove both tokens in the client and the access token will eventually expire for good.

Reissue tokens: It's a simpler and more naive version of the previous. Add a reissue token functionality that let's you update the current token (call AuthToken.issue_token in your code again). Your client can call it sometime before the current token expires.

Blacklist tokens: In this case you would need to store the previously used tokens in the database, which kind of defeats the purpose because you would have to constantly validate against the database instead of just decoding.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot logout with JWT unless you blacklist tokens you revoked (this means you lose all the benefits provided by the JWT).
I recommend you to set a lower token lifetime (e.g. 5 min instead of 24 hrs) and renew the token through a refresh token (lifetime could be 24 hrs) if it is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your message and I think I understand what you say. However I have the task to implement also a logout button in my android app. How could I still do that with my JWT and Devise ruby on rails programm?

Comment: You just have to delete the JWT from your app when the logout button is pressed.

Comment: How can I do that? do I need to implement this in my ruby on rails app? What line do I need to write in my android app?